# Align text center to table header and right to siblings(html - table)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am frequently encountering this type of design in my projects. I want a cell text aligned to center of the header and right aligned to the below and above data as shown below. And table has border. The three cells shown in image are in different rows. How can I do this one?

I tried with `text-align:center` but it aligns everything to the center. Tried with `padding` but nothing seems to work. I tried to `text-align: right` but it is not aligning with header.

[image]

Comment: I tried many ways but remained nothing. Have to find a way

Comment: Do you want the 0 to be right aligned with both the above and bottom rows ?

Comment: No, only with bottom. I mean if there is any data above the zero which is not header then it should align. But there is no data above the 0. It's just an example to show above one is header and below one is row data

Comment: And does it necessarily have to be done in html table?

Comment: not sure, you can tell me using `<div>` as well. If possible tell me using `<table>` as well

Comment: Why did you unmark it ?

Comment: Three cells should be in different rows of same table

Comment: Yeah well, if it was possible to use just one table to achieve that without using something else someone would have posted a solution. Good luck with that :)

Answer (score 2):

```html
    <div style="text-align: center;">This is my header</div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: right;">
       <div class="inner_container">0</div>
       <div class="inner_container">123444</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You could try something like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">This is my header</div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: right;">
            <div class="inner_container">0</div>
            <div class="inner_container">123444</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty good. As my comment to the question, you gave one solution and above answer is takes 50% credit. 50-50

Answer (score 2):

As you can see you can make use of a `parent table` and a `child table` for achieving this as demonstrated below. Align the child table to the center of parent using `margin` and align the contents of the `first and second child` as you need.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#parent {
  width: 100%;
}

#child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#child tr:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}

#child tr:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="parent">
    <tr>
      <th>Header content</th>
    </tr>
    <tr width="100%">
      <table id="child">
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123344</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks nice. As my comment to the question, you gave one solution and below answer is takes 50% credit. 50-50

Comment: No problem :) As shown in the other answer it can be achieved fairly easily using div instead of table cells but here's a workaround as well if you need it.